# Am I allowed to provide the Camera Ready Copy (CRC) / Preprint of my paper published in Springer Workshop Proceedings online on my homepage?

Tags: copyright, online-publication, workshop, springer, proceedings

my work was accepted as workshop paper and the conference was held some weeks ago. Until now, the paper is nowhere published. Last year, the Spriner Workshop Proceedings needed 6 months to publish it. I want to provide the paper now on my homepage and/or research gate and/or arXiv.

Am I allowed to provide the CRC version on my homepage/research gate/arXiv? What do I need to add to this "pre-print", e.g. as footnote? What are the typical Spriner Workshop Proceedings rules regarding providing the own work? And I am allowed to do this before it is officially published by Springer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Springer Copyright transfer agreement that you would have signed explains what is allowed.

Comment: To avoid problems (in the future), put work online before signing copyright transfer agreements. (Noting that there may exist venues at which publication will be precluded.)

Comment: @GoodDeeds The only thing I have signed in advance of the workshop was about the recording during the conference. I never got any document from Springer. I also just submitted the pdf, not the latex sources. But since some months this seems to be ongoing practice by Springer...

Comment: @user3352632 Then you probably have not submitted the camera ready for the proceedings yet (which could be different from what the workshop page used). Also, not all workshops have official proceedings, so check that. I don't know what's typical, but I have usually seen Springer allow putting papers on arXiv. For example, the agreement for LNCS is [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I do not see any reason you cannot. If you like, you put a header or footer that the paper was presented in ABC conference and the official version can be downloaded from the Springer website to save yourself from copyright issues. But I think, even without that header you should be fine. (Still, having that line in header/footer is better).

Putting it on Arxiv is more wise and professional by the way. It can give your work credibility and readability as well.